# Conversion code Mathematica 5.0 to Matlab

Tags: conversion

- How to convert the following Mathematica code into Matlab?
- What is the corresponding Matlab code?

```
Clear[defvar]
defvar[{Nh_Symbol, Nhf_Symbol, gini_Symbol}, {dim_Integer, steps_Integer}] :=
  Module[{cN, cNf, ginix},
   cN = Array[Nh, dim];
   cNf = Array[Nhf, dim];
   ginix = Array[gini, steps];
   {cN, cNf, ginix}
  ];
```

Here is an example of using the code above:

```
Clear[Nh, Nhf, gini]
defvar[{Nh, Nhf, gini}, {10, 1}]
```

---

### Original post

I am new to the forum and I am also a newbie to programming. I want to convert a Mathematica code to Matlab, but I don't understand how to translate these lines. This code is Mathematica 5.0.

```
defvar := Module[{a},
Clear[ cN, cNf, ginix ];
Clear[ Nh, Nhf, gini ];
cN = Array[Nh, dim]; cNf = Array[Nhf, dim];
ginix = Array[gix, steps];]
```

where dim = 1000; steps = 1.

I thank you very much!

Comment: The code shown would be bad even if V5.0 were current rather than ancient. I don't see how anyone could be expected to translate such bad code into good current Matlab without having a description of the problem domain from which the code is derived.

Answer (score 4):

Let's look at your code to understand the problems and identify what it does and doesn't do.

This may enable you to develop the Matlab code you want.
I don't think you'll get much help from this forum in doing a translation.

Formatting the so you have each sub-statement on a single line will help you understand it a bit better:

```
defvar := Module[{a},
  Clear[cN, cNf, ginix];
  Clear[Nh, Nhf, gini];
  cN = Array[Nh, dim];
  cNf = Array[Nhf, dim];
  ginix = Array[gix, steps];
  ]
```

`defvar :=` ... defines a bespoke function and the left side of an expression.

In the code `defvar` has no parameters passed to it, which it could if you have code something like the following, which enables one to pass 3 parameters to the function:

```
defvar[x_, y_, z_]:= something...
```

Everything within the right side of the expression resides in the native Mathematica function `Module`, which ring fences the variable shown with the curly brackets `{a}`.

First problem, the function `defvar` doesn't use `a` for anything.  It has a local variable, but it doesn't use it.

Next, you have two statements which use `Clear`:

```
  Clear[cN, cNf, ginix];
  Clear[Nh, Nhf, gini];
```

These statements clear the value of the six listed variables: `cN`, `cNf`, `ginix`,`Nh`, `Nhf`, and `gini`.  First thought, these look like global variables in a Notebook, but they could also reside in i.e., a higher level function or Module.

The code then assigns values to the "global varialbes`cN`, `CNf`, and `ginix`.

Since the code, preceding these value assignments, clears `Nh`, `Nhf`, and `ginix` the assignments for these variables appear to only assign symbolic values.

The code posted does not have any internally received or generated values for `dim` or `steps` or `gix`.

`fix` would set symbolically, but unless the `defvar` function can access integers for `dim` and `steps` the array generation won't work.

`dim` and `steps` may exist as global variable in some larger code.

Finally, while the `defvar` function may do something in the right larger environment, it does not return anything.  It has no output.

As example...

```
defvar := Module[{a},
  Clear[cN, cNf, ginix];
  Clear[Nh, Nhf, gini];
  cN = Array[Nh, dim];
  cNf = Array[Nhf, dim];
  ginix = Array[gix, steps]
  ]
```

notice that I removed the last semicolon in the code.  This would enable the function to return the defined array, `ginix`.

Another possibility...

Something like the following would enable it to output all of the defined arrays:

```
    defvar := Module[{a},
      Clear[cN, cNf, ginix];
      Clear[Nh, Nhf, gini];

      {
        cN = Array[Nh, dim],
        cNf = Array[Nhf, dim],
        ginix = Array[gix, steps]
      }
      ]
```

but it's hard to speculate about what you want to do without more information.

Comment: Check this package for transforming syntax to matlab. https://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/577/

Comment: @qahtah -- Great link, but maybe better to add it as a comment on the OP's original post rather than an answer.   That said, post it as an answer and I'll upvote it.

Comment: Thank you @Jagra for your amability. The code of question is a extract of code in this next link (bottom of page): https://faculty.wcas.northwestern.edu/~mdo738/research.html, of paper "Inequality and Growth: Why Differential Fertility Matters". Thank you!

Comment: Thank you @qahtah!